# Backfilling from another data.frame

Tags: r

I frequently have situations where I have to "fill in" information from another data source.

For example:

```
x <- data.frame(c1=letters[1:26],c2=letters[26:1])
x[x$c1 == "m","c2"] <- NA
x[x$c1 == "a","c2"] <- NA

   c1   c2
1   a <NA>
2   b    y
3   c    x
4   d    w
5   e    v
6   f    u
7   g    t
8   h    s
9   i    r
10  j    q
11  k    p
12  l    o
13  m <NA>
...
```

Now, with that missing variable, I'd like to check and fill it in using a seperate data.frame, lets' call it `y`

```
y <- data.frame(c1=c("m","a"),c2=c("n","z"))
```

So, what I would like to happen is for x to be filled in with y. (row 13 should be c("m","n"), row 1 should be c("a","z"))

The method I use to deal with this currently seems convoluted and indirect. What would your approach be? Keeping in mind that my data is not necessarily in a nice order like this one is but the order should be maintained in `x`. My preference would be for a solution that does not rely on anything but base R.

Comment: In your data, does `y` contain only one row, as in the example? Or does it have other unrelated data? Also, I'm guessing you can have multiple `NA`s in your `x` data frame? Are they always in `$c2`?

Comment: The example is simplied, but in my real data there are multiple rows of data to be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

This will be a far simpler proposition if you deal with `character` variables, not `factors`.

I will present a simple  `data.table` solution (for elegant and easy to use syntax amongst many other advantages)

```
x <- data.frame(c1=letters[1:26],c2=letters[26:1], stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
x[x$c1 == "m","c2"] <- NA
y <- data.frame(c1="m",c2="n", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(data.table)
X <- as.data.table(x)
Y <- as.data.table(y)
```

For simplicity of merging, I will create a column that indicating

```
X[,missing_c2 := is.na(c2)]
# a similar column in Y
Y[,missing_c2 := TRUE]

setkey(X, c2, missing_c2)
setkey(Y, c2, missing_c2)
# merge and replace (by reference) those values in X with the the values in `Y` 
X[Y, c2 := i.c2]
```

The `i.c2` means that we use the values of `c2` from the `i` argument to `[`

This approach assumes that not all values where `c1 = 'm'` will be missing in `X` and you don't want to replace all values in `c2` with `'m'` where `c1='m'`, only those which are missing

---

## A base solution

Here is a base solution -- I use merge so that the `y` data.frame can contain more `missing` replacements than actually needed (i.e. could have values for all `c1` values, although only `c1=`m`` is required.

```
  # add a second missing value row because to make the solution more generalizable
x <- rbind(x, data.frame(c1 = 'm',c2 = NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )
missing <- x[is.na(x$c2),]
merged <- merge(missing, y, by = 'c1')

x[is.na(x$c2),] <- with(merged, data.frame(c1 = c1, c2 = c2.y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

If you use `factors` you will come up against a wall of pain ensuring that the levels correspond.

Comment: +1 data.table looks awesome, but for this particular problem I'd like to stay with base.

Comment: Why not add what you are already doing to your question then -- then the answers may address your *real* problem. When does merge not act intuitively?

Comment: I stand by the fact if you are looking for different approaches, then add the approach to the question  that you would like the answers to differ from.

Comment: re: merge, it doesn't act intuitively when there are NA values involved - incomparables get pushed to the bottom (ie, resorted without notifying the user, rather than staying "in place").

Comment: I feel like the data.table version worked for me yesterday at home, but isn't on my work computer. What version of data.table were you using?

Answer (score 2):

In base R, I believe this will work for you:

```
nas <- is.na(x$c2)
x[nas, ] <- y[y$c1 %in% x[nas, 1], ]
```

Comment: Yes, I like this, my only issue is that when I use this on my real data. The true-false values are unsorted so it returns values where order doesn't matter, but in my example it does. I'm not sure how to reflect this in my question. I'll think on it a bit and update shortly.

Comment: I think you need to `merge` and then replace, see my solution.

Comment: Ah, I see - I didn't understand your original question. In that case I think @mnel's right.